# Volatile keyword on Atomic Variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile, atomicinteger

The following code is valid in Java

```
volatile AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(123);
```

Do we require `volatile` keyword on Atomic variables such as [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)? Or is `volatile` superfluous?

Comment: You probably should make it `final`, instead of `volatile`. If `final` doesn't work for you, then you are either doing something very tricky, or else you may be making a mistake. Don't forget that the variable `a` is _not_ an `AtomicInteger`. The `a` variable holds a _reference_ to a mutable `AtomicInteger` heap object. In the normal way of using `AtomicInteger`, the different parts of your  program and its different threads would all communicate by mutating and inspecting the same shared object, and _not_ by changing which object the `a` variable refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's superfluous for most sane use cases, but conceivably applicable to some weird cases -- not that I can think of any.  When in doubt, use `final`.

Answer (score 0):

volatile is superfluous because the variable inside the AtomicInteger already is volatile and will provide the happens-before relation that is required. Just make the field final.